# I would like to return a variable and text in the same function

Tags: php, function

I have written a function:

```
public function title()
{
return ($location->cityName);

}
```

I would like the function to return the city name, but also with text either side of it.

e.g **Information in** London **Today**

I have tried writing:

```
return (('Information in'))$location->cityName('Today'));
```

But this didn't work, I have also tried an echo statement before and after the return.

Comment: Why don't you return an array, with information in, city name and time?

Comment: The elements called in the function are not defined.

Comment: @Gimmy may be the function is inside a class and `$location` is a class variable

Comment: @pinkpanther then it'd be called like `$this->location`

Comment: @Maerlyn if `$location` is an instance of another class declared in this class ?

Comment: That's how it works in php, you need to reference them using `$this`.

Comment: @Maerlyn if `$location` is a variable storing an object inside the current class and it has an attribute `cityName` then we should call `$this->location->cityName`? `$location->cityName` doesn't work?

Comment: @pinkpanther That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) .
The following code should do what you want:

```
public function title()
{
  return 'Information in ' . $location->cityName . ' Today';
}
```

Comment: Patrick, thank you, this worked first time. The link to the string concatenation was very useful too.

Answer (score 1):

For concatenation of two strings in `PHP`, we use a '.' operator as we use '+' in `Java` or `Javascript`.

Change the line like this

```
 return "Information in ".$location->cityName." Today";
```

**EDIT:** Thanks to Patrick

When we use double quotes we can write away like this with out operator

```
 return "Information in $location->cityName Today";
```

Comment: In this case, you're using double quotes, so you don't need string concatenation.

Comment: @felipe.zkn what did you say...seems like an interesting point... `.` is not needed?

Comment: @felipe.zkn no that's not working `.` is needed

Comment: If you use a variable inside a double quoted string, PHP uses the value of the variable.

Comment: @pinkpanther You can remove both the quotes and the dot. Your could would then look like this: `return "Information in $location->cityName Today";`

Comment: @Patrick +1...yep that's how I used to write sql query strings...thanks

Comment: @pinkpanther, I hope you don't anymore because that makes SQL-injections pretty easy. I didn't use that method in my answer though because you can't insert any variable that way.

Comment: @Patrick sorry I didn't get you.... is it better to use double quotes with out dot operator ?

Comment: @pinkpanther, you said you were using this to write your SQL-query strings. From that I assumed you were using the way of inlining the variables to build your SQL-query's. If that was the case, it would be easy to do SQL-injections, since you probably wouldn't have done any checks on the user input. 
I don't think one of the two ways (the one in my answer or your edit) is better, it's just a matter of preference. It is good to know though, that the way in your edit won't work if you want to insert array elements into your string.

Comment: It's more secure to use escape functions accordingly to your database: for example, mysqli_real_escape_string. In general, you need to treat data before using it.

Comment: @Patrick;@felipe.zkn both gave good pointers thanks :)